# C# check if value exists in database error

Tags: c#

When I want to check if the program exists in the database entry gives me an error:

> Keyword not supported: 'datasource'

My code:

```
public bool FindString(string myString)
{
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=admin;password=admin"; 
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "Create Procedure FindString(@MyString nvarchar(50)) as Begin Select * test.user Where Value = @MyString End";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyString", myString);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                connection.Close();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And the code to use the class:

```
ReadData r = new ReadData();

if (r.FindString(textBox1.Text))
   MessageBox.Show("I Found it!");
else
   MessageBox.Show("I can't Find it!");
```

Answer (score 2):

The keyword "datasource" does not exist in the context of the configuration of ConnectionString. You should use "date source" as two separate words instead:

```
connection.ConnectionString = "data source=localhost;port=3306;username=admin;password=admin";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySQL: `SqlConnection` is for SQL Server. Use `MySqlConnection` instead.

If you don't have the .Net connector for MySQL yet, you can download it [from here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) : it's **data source** in two separated words

Answer (score 0):

[Look here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) I supose you write bad connectionString. As @bejger wrote, you need to write "data source"